# What do the round brackets mean in this expression? (&net.Dialer{Timeout: 5 * time.Second}).DialContext

Tags: http, go

```
&http.Client{
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                DialContext:         (&net.Dialer{Timeout: 5 * time.Second}).DialContext,
                TLSHandshakeTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
            },
            Timeout: 15 * time.Second,
        },
```

In this code snippet why the DialContext field value is in the round brackets?

`(&net.Dialer{Timeout: 5 * time.Second}).DialContext,`

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

It's for grouping expressions.

Without the parenthesis it would mean:

```
&(net.Dialer{Timeout: 5 * time.Second}.DialContext)
```

So it would mean to take the address of the `net.Dialer.DialContext` method, which is obviously not the intent.

The intent is to create a [`*net.Dialer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer) value (by taking the address of a `net.Dialer{}` [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)), and use a [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) to obtain a function value being the `net.Dialer` method that will be assigned to the [`Transport.DialContext`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) field which is of function type

```
func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error)
```

[`Dialer.DialContext()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer.DialContext) has the same signature with an additional receiver type:

```
func (d *Dialer) DialContext(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (Conn, error)
```

Which is OK because the method value is of a function type without the receiver type.